# How to use ScriptManager with Razor in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I used ScriptManager in .aspx page to Maintain **URL history** in .Net i.e.

on **aspx page** i put this script after form tag

```
> <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true"
>         EnableHistory="true">       
>     </asp:ScriptManager>
```

and in my **.js** file i put this code

```
Sys.Application.add_navigate(function (sender, e) {
    navigate(sender, e);
});

 Sys.Application.addHistoryPoint(objOut, null);
```

Now same thing i want to use in **MVC 4 with Razor**

I used **MicrosoftAjax.js** for ScriptManager and .js code is same.
but i am getting issue on callback.

let me explain you with example:

```
suppose Actual URL is
www.websitename.com/cat/30/

anchor tag link on page is 
www.websitename.com/cat/30/?q=10

once callback perform anchor tag link becomes
www.websitename.com/?q=10
```

I mean after callback "**cat/30/**" is missing from link.

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Ashu

Comment: You wouldn't, you'd declare the JavaScript file in the View.

Answer (score 3):

`ScriptManager` is part of `ASP.NET Webforms`. It is not available in `ASP.NET MVC`. They are two completely different frameworks.

There is a port of `ScriptManager` to `ASP.NET MVC` which is available [here](http://mvcscriptmanager.codeplex.com/). It might provide what you are looking for.